# Sending Crash Report via Email from Android App

Tags: java, android, email, system, crash-reports

hey guys i need help configuring some source code to basically when a error happens to send a crash report via email to me. Here is some code im playing with i just need someone with a little more experience with java to overlook it and help me clean it up.

Thanks,

```
public final class EmailUtils {

private EmailUtils()
 {
 }

private static int bytesToMb(long l)
 {
    return (int)((double)l / 1024D / 1024D);
 }

private static int getAvailableInternalMemorySize()
 {
    StatFs statfs = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath());
    return bytesToMb((long)statfs.getBlockSize() * (long)statfs.getAvailableBlocks());
 }

private static String getEmailText(Context context)
 {
    String s = "";
    String s11;
    PackageInfo packageinfo =  context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
    String s1 = packageinfo.versionName;
    int i = packageinfo.versionCode;
    String s2 = packageinfo.packageName;
    String s3 = Build.MODEL;
    String s4 = android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
    String s5 = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK;
    String s6 = Build.DEVICE;
    String s7 = Build.DISPLAY;
    String s8 = Build.ID;
    String s9 = (new  StringBuilder(String.valueOf(Build.BRAND))).append("/").append(Build.MANUFACTURER).toString();
    String s10 = Build.PRODUCT;
    s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("\n\n------------------\n").toString();
    s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("Version: ").append(s1).toString();
    s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("\n").toString();
    s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("Version num: ").append(i).toString();
    s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("\n").toString();
    s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("Package: ").append(s2).toString();
    s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("\n").toString();
    s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("Phone Model: ").append(s3).toString();
    s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("\n").toString();
    s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("Android Version: ").append(s4).toString();
    s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("\n").toString();
    s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("SDK Version: ").append(s5).toString();
    s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("\n").toString();
    s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("Device: ").append(s6).toString();
    s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("\n").toString();
    s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("Product: ").append(s10).toString();
    s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("\n").toString();
    s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("Brand: ").append(s9).toString();
    s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("\n").toString();
    s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("Disp: ").append(s7).toString();
    s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("\n").toString();
    s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("Id: ").append(s8).toString();
    s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("\n").toString();
    s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("Available Internal memory: ").append(getAvailableInternalMemorySize()).append("/").append(getTotalInternalMemorySize()).append(" Mb").toString();
    s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("\n").toString();
    s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("Heap size: ").append(getHeapSizeMb()).append(" Mb").toString();
    s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("\n").toString();
    s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("Mar: GO").toString();
    s11 = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("\n").toString();
    s = s11;

    android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException namenotfoundexception;

 //   namenotfoundexception.printStackTrace();
  //  if(true) 
  //    goto

}

private static int getHeapSizeMb()
 {
    return bytesToMb(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory());
 }

private static int getTotalInternalMemorySize()
 {
    StatFs statfs = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath());
    return bytesToMb((long)statfs.getBlockSize() * (long)statfs.getBlockCount());
 }

public static void sendContactEmail(Context context)
 {
    String s = context.getResources().getString(0x7f040000);
    String s1 = "";
    String s2;
    String s3;
    Intent intent;
    try
    {
        s1 = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(),  0).versionName;
    }
    catch(android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException  namenotfoundexception) { }
    s2 = (new StringBuilder("[SUPPORT] ")).append(s).append(" ").append(s1).toString();
    s3 = getEmailText(context);
    intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
    intent.setType("plain/text");
    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.EMAIL", new String[] {
        "support@myemail.com"
    });
    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.SUBJECT", s2);
    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT", s3);
    if(context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0).size() > 0)
    {
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail..."));
    } else
    {
        CustomAlertDialogBuilder customalertdialogbuilder = new CustomAlertDialogBuilder(context);
        customalertdialogbuilder.setTitle("Contact us");
        customalertdialogbuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        customalertdialogbuilder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("No application found to send emails.<br /><br />Please contact us at: <b>support@email.com</b>."));
        customalertdialogbuilder.setNegativeButton("Close", null);
        customalertdialogbuilder.show();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work? Any errors? Whats the question?

Comment: @wtsang02 I cant seem to get the Syntax formatting correct. I cant seem to figure out the packmanager stuff. such as the out commented section namenotfoundexception. i can figure out what more code i need to insert to make this work. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't just using ACRA for this? http://acra.ch/

Comment: @CommonsWare The answer is yes and its becuase i dont know how to use it. thanks for the link, ill check it out. Any ideas on how im doing it right now? Mainly all im trying to do is included system info into a series of strings that i can intent into email app to send to me.

Comment: Well, to be honest, your code is a mess. Once I saw you were hard-coding a frequently-invalid string resource hex ID value, I figured the better answer was to convince you to completely dump this code and use something that is already implemented and supported. Beyond the resource problem: the MIME type is `text/plain`, not `plain/text`; you should be using `Intent` static data members instead of hard-coded strings like `"android.intent.action.SEND"`; your series-of-`StringBuilder` objects is ghastly; etc.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for replying and included support for me, i appreciate it. im very new to android/programing so please help understand if i can very basic questions. My Main goal is to pull system data and intent out. Do you recommend using the ACRA way or using my string method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My Main goal is to pull system data and intent out. Do you recommend using the ACRA way or using my string method?

Definitely ACRA. Again, it already exists, is supported, offers multiple means of getting the data to you (including ways that do not disclose your email address), integrates with third-party services like BugSense, etc.

To be a bit more specific about two of my code comments:

- Never never never never never never never hard-code a resource ID hex value, such as: `String s = context.getResources().getString(0x7f040000);`. Those values can change with each build, particularly when you add/remove resources. Always use the resource ID symbol (e.g., `R.string.foo`).
- In `getEmailText()`, please create *one* `StringBuilder` object and append to it. Do not create 30 or so of them, using each once and discarding it.

Comment: i really appreciate you providing me with this information. I think im going to put the code above on hold and look into ACRA more. Thanks